# Lower and upper bound for order of subgroup generated by a subset

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $A\subseteq G$.

Is there any (non-trivial and useful) lower bound for $\lvert\langle A \rangle\rvert$
(order of the subgroup generated by $A$)? What about upper bound?

Answer (score 1):

All the finite simple groups are $2$-generated, so I guess the answer is no for the upper bound.

**Addendum** See for instance [this survey paper](http://www.ams.org/notices/200104/fea-shalev.pdf) by Aner Shalev, in which he mentions (p. 386, following Theorem 5) that if $G$ is a finite simple groups, and $x \in G$ is an arbitrary element, different from the identity, then there is $y \in G$ such that $\langle x, y \rangle = G$.